# Oscillation of Riemann-Liouville process after hitting time

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $W$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion and let $X_t = \int_0^t (t-s)^{H - 1/2} \mathrm{d} W_t$, $H \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$ be a Riemann-Liouville process. We set
$$ \sigma(a) := \inf \{t > 0 : X_t = a\}.$$
Can we prove that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ almost surely for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $s, t \in (\sigma(a), \sigma(a) + \epsilon)$ such that $X_s < a$ and $X_t > a$? This is well-known for the Brownian motion.

I think I can prove this for $a = 0$. Indeed, to prove it by contradiction, suppose that
$$ \mathbb{P}(X \geq 0 \text{ in a neighborhood of } t = 0) > 0. $$
By Bluementhal's $0$-$1$ law, the probability must be $1$. Then, using the symmetry, we see
$$\mathbb{P}(X = 0 \text{ in a neighborhood of } t = 0) = 1. $$
Injectivity of Riemann-Liouville kernel shows that $W = 0$ around $t = 0$, contradiction.

But I am interested in the case $a \neq 0$. Then, you have to deal with the past part. Because of that, I don't know how to prove the question. (If the laws of $X_{\sigma(a)+t}-a, t \leq T$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $(X_t)_{t \leq T}$ the claim follows, but I don't know if this is ture.)

Answer (score 0):

The following is for $\epsilon\geq c\vee 1$ for some random constant. For less than $c$, it is unclear how to modify the argument below. Perhaps some scaling argument can do it.

Also, the following is proving a much stronger result, than what you ask because I tried to do with local time since fBM doesn't have any Markov property. So a weaker argument should work to give it for all $\epsilon$; any ideas are welcome.

The local time $\ell_{x,t}$ of fractional Brownian motio is continuous eg.["A uniform result for the dimension of fractional Brownian motion level sets"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.01423) or "On the local time of multifractional Brownian motion"

and from "Occupation time problems for fractional Brownian motion and some other self-similar processes"

[image]

Suppose by symmetry that fBM starts at $x<a$. So consider $A_{r}=(a,a+r)$ and $A_{-r}=(a-r,a)$ and their occupation times during $I=:[\sigma(a),\sigma(a)+\epsilon]$

$$\mu_{I}(A_{r})=\int_{A_{r}}\ell_{I,x}dx, \mu_{I}(A_{-r})=\int_{A_{r}}\ell_{I,x}dx.$$

Now by contradiction suppose that only one of those occupation time is zero, say $ \mu_{I}(A_{-r})=0$. Both occupation measures cannot be both zero because that would imply that fBM either jumps (but it is continuous) or it is constant equal to $a$ but in fact it is nowhere differentiable; this can be proved with local time continuity as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748504/proof-of-non-differentiability-of-brownian-motion-using-local-times). So we get $ \mu_{I}(A_{r})>0$.

However, we use bound $E[\ell_{x,I}]\geq E[\ell_{x+r,I}]-c|I|^{1-H(1+\delta)}r^{\delta}$ to get

$$0= E[\mu_{I}(A_{-r})]> E[\mu_{I}(A_{r}) -c|I|^{1-H(1+\delta)}r^{\delta+1}].$$

By taking large enough $r$ (eg. $r>c_{Holder}\epsilon^{H-s}$ for $s>0$), we get $ \mu_{I}(A_{r})=|I|=\epsilon>0$ and so

$$0= E[\mu_{I}(A_{-r})]> E[\epsilon-c_{1}\epsilon^{1-H(1+\delta)}r^{\delta+1}].$$

Since $\epsilon>c\vee 1$ for some large random $c$ depending on $c_{Holder},c_{1}$, we get $\epsilon^{H}>r>c_{Holder}\epsilon^{H-s}$ and so

$$1-c_{1}(\frac{r}{\epsilon^{H}})^{1+\delta}=1-c_{1}(c_{Holder}\epsilon^{-s_{1}})^{1+\delta}>0$$

for $s_{1}<s$.

Comment: To be clear the last few computations step are meant with expectations since the Holder estimate is for Lp.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. You can easily see $\mu(A_r \cup A_{-r}) > 0$ by the occupation density formula. I am not very sure if you can apply the cited result, since the interval length $\epsilon$ of $I$ is random. If we allow $\epsilon$ to be randomly large, we can use the recurrence. But as you suggest, maybe the claim follows by proving $\operatorname{supp}(\mathrm{d} L_{\cdot}(a)) = \{t: X_t = a\}$, the proof of which is not clear, though.

Comment: actually I used another result. I now removed the previous result with random interval $I$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: How would you use $ supp(dL⋅(a))=\{t:X_t=a\}$, to get it? Because after all local time $L_{t,a}$ is indeed the limit of arbitrarily small neighbourhood around a up to time t.

Comment: For the arbitrarily small epsilon case, ideally I want to take r very large so that $\mu(A_{r})=\epsilon$, but then I cannot longer use continuity of local time. To use that continuity I need r to be small.

Comment: As for the support of the local time, I was thinking to use something like Corollary 4.8 from https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.01686. It is easy to see $\operatorname{supp}(\mathrm{d} L_{\cdot}(a) \subseteq \{t : X_t = a\}$, but the other inclusion is not obvious.